# Load local text file with Windows Metro Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I have tried to no avail, to find how to load a **local** text file in JS.  By local I mean a file in the app's directory.

In python I would do this:

```
file = open('file.txt','r')
loadedList = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

Is there a JS equivalent without jQuery.

This is a Windows store app by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify files included in the appx package with the ms-appx: protocol and can read it with the Windows Runtime StorageFile and FileIO classes. See [Quickstart: Reading and writing files (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464978.aspx) and the [File access sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=231445).

```
var fileName = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///file.txt");
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileName).then(function (file) {
    Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (fileContent) {
        loadedList = fileContent;
    });
});
```

A less general trick is to use the WinJS.xhr function to read from the project file:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "file.txt" }).then(function (result) {
    loadedList= result.responseText;
});
```